# Refresh token flow : Loopback

Tags: authentication, authorization, token, loopbackjs, strongloop

How to implement the refresh token flow in Loopback 3.x ?

Some have recommended to refresh the 'created' columns of access token table, so the access token does not expire. But this results in a 'long-lived' access token. This is a security flaw.